# Reshaping a time-series into multiple features, each corresponding to the course of a day

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a time-series, properly interpreted as such by Pandas, that corresponds to one heart-rate measure per minute over many days.

I need to know what's the idiomatic way (if any) of converting this into a set (DataFrame, etc.) wiht mutiple time-series, each ranging from 00:00 to 23:59.

---

There's obviously a brute-force way of doing this by taking slices with 24*60 rows. But in the general case there may be all kinds of failures, such as irregular samples (taken within the 1 minute waiting window because of how the software in the wrist band monitor tries to detect exercise, sleep etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky solution that works

```py
dg = df[['start_time', 'heart_rate']].set_index('start_time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))

dh = pd.DataFrame()

for name, group in dg:
    timestamps = pd.Series([val.time() for val in group.index])
    group = group.rename(columns={"heart_rate": str(name.date())})
    group.index = timestamps
    dh = pd.concat([dh,group],axis=1)
```

but I'm sure there's something more idiomatic in Pandas.